# $dX_t/X_t=\mu\, dt+\sigma \, dZ_t$, does this notation make sense?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals

I understand that the notation

$$dX_t=\mu X_t \,dt + \sigma X_t \,dZ_t,$$

where $Z_t$ is Brownian Motion, is a shortcut to

$$X_t-X_0=\int_0^t\mu X_s \, ds+\int_0^t \sigma X_s \, dZ_s, \tag{*}$$

which has a precise meaning, since the Ito integral is defined.

But I don't get it when people write:

$$\frac{dX_t}{X_t}=\mu \, dt + \sigma \, dZ_t,$$

and later go on defining $\frac{dX_t}{X_t}$ as a variable. What does $\frac{dX_t}{X_t}$ even mean? To me, it looks like taking $X_s$ out of the integral in $(*)$, which does not make any sense.

For example, if $X_t$ is the price of an asset, $dX_t/X_t$ is sometimes defined as the rate of return the asset, but my point is that it is not even a mathematically defined object.

Am I missing something, or this is sloppy?

Comment: Imo: it's just sloppy (it's finance, so.....)

Comment: This is indeed a finance thing as @saz pointed out. But it is legitimate to consider the Euler discretization scheme $X_{t + \Delta t} = X_t + \Delta X_t$ with $\Delta X_t = \mu X_t \Delta t + \sigma X_t \Delta Z_t$ where $\Delta Z_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sqrt{\Delta t})$. So then $\frac{\Delta X_t}{X_t}$, which is indeed the return on $X$ between $t$ and $t + \Delta t$, is given by $\mu \Delta t + \sigma\Delta Z_t$, which is approximated by the $\mu dt + \sigma dZ_t$. It is sloppy and just plain wrong perhaps from a mathematical point of view but not that meaningless in the context of finance.

Comment: This is not the only notational abuse you will encounter in finance. If you haven't already done so, you will encounter things like $E[dX_t]$, $(dZ_t)^2 = dt$, $dZ_t dt = 0$, $E_s[X_t]$ (this is perhaps not a big deal if the filtration you are referring to is clear from the context but that is not always the case). They are all "justified" by some reasoning that pertains to financial considerations.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{dx_t}{x_t}=\mu+\sigma dz_t\\$$let $f(x)=ln(x)$ apply ito formula to find $df(x)$ $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial x^2}\\df=0dt+\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{x^2})dx^2\\df=0dt+\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{x^2})dx^2\\$$now put $dx_t=\mu x_tdt+\sigma x_t dz_t$
$$df=0dt+\frac{1}{x_t}(\mu x_tdt+\sigma x_t dz_t)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{x_t^2})(\mu x_tdt+\sigma x_t dz_t)^2\\$$
$$df=0dt+\frac{1}{x_t}(\mu x_tdt+\sigma x_t dz_t)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{x_t^2})(\mu^2 x_t^2(dt)^2+\sigma^2 x^2_t (dz_t)^2+2\mu \sigma x^2_tdtdz_t)^2\\$$
apply $dt.dt \to 0\\dt.dz_t \to 0 \\dz_t.dz_t \to dt$
so 
$$df=0dt+\mu dt +\sigma dz_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 dt$$apply integral for both sides
$$\int_{0}^{t}d(lnx_s)=\int_{0}^{t}(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma dz_s\\ \ln(x_t)-\ln(x_0)=\int_{0}^{t}(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma dz_s\\\frac{x_t}{x_0}=e^{\int_{0}^{t}(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma dz_s}\\x_t=x_0.e^{\int_{0}^{t}(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma dz_s}$$

Comment: Related to the question?

Comment: I think it is about third line of the question...(I do not answer his question ,but I want to help for exact solution )

Comment: Maybe the readers like more rigorous explanation. However your reasoning seems quite sensible at the calculus level (and not analysis level).